# Python pandas check dataframe duplicate value as a condition in loc

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel file in which I need to follow certain conditions and input in remarks column if it satisfy the condition. I get the necessary columns as DataFrames and here is how it looks:

```
svc_no   i_status   caller_id   f_status   result      remarks
11111    WO         11111       WO         Not Match   Duplicate svc_no 
22222    WO         22222       WO         Match
11111    WO         n/a         SP         Not Match   Duplicate svc_no
```

The conditions would  be:

- The svc_no is duplicated
- One of the duplicate is equal value with caller_id
- The other has a value of '*n/a*' or '*NULL*' in caller_id
- Result is *Not Match*

I used `.loc` and write it this way

```
df.loc[(df['svc_no'] != 'NULL') & (df['svc_no'] == df['caller_id']) & (df['svc_no'].duplicated()) & (df['i_status'] == 'WO') & (df['f_status'] == 'WO') & (df['result'] == 'Not Match), [remarks]] = 'Duplicate svc_no'
```

This code maybe right for the row where the first duplicate appeared, it does not apply to the other row where the other duplicate appeared.

Question: Is there a way where I can compare two rows with duplicates and apply necessary conditions using `.loc` or is there a way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you want as your desired output. But you can find all `svc_no` covered by your criteria using a sequence of Boolean masks:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'svc_no': [11111, 22222, 11111],
                   'caller_id': [11111, 22222, 'n/a'],
                   'result': ['Not Match', 'Match', 'Not Match']})

counts = df['svc_no'].value_counts()
grouper = df.groupby('svc_no')['caller_id']

cond1 = df['svc_no'].isin(counts[counts > 1].index)
cond2 = df['svc_no'].isin(df.loc[df['svc_no'] == df['caller_id'], 'svc_no'])
cond3 = df['svc_no'].isin(df.loc[grouper.apply(lambda x: x.isin(['n/a', 'NULL'])), 'svc_no'])
cond4 = df['svc_no'].isin(df.loc[df['result'] == 'Not Match', 'svc_no'])

df.loc[cond1 & cond2 & cond3 & cond4, 'remarks'] = 'Duplicate svc_no'

print(df)

  caller_id     result  svc_no           remarks
0     11111  Not Match   11111  Duplicate svc_no
1     22222      Match   22222               NaN
2       n/a  Not Match   11111  Duplicate svc_no
```

Comment: My desired output would be, after I satisfy the conditions, I will input string *Duplicate svc_no* in the remarks column. Though my problem is that my code applies for the first found duplicate value only.

Comment: @RickyAguilar, OK, I've updated, not sure it's *exactly* what you want, but it produces your desired output.

Comment: There was a SytaxError on `df.loc[cond1 & cond2 & cond3 & cond4, 'remarks'] = 'Duplicate svc_no'~`

Comment: @RickyAguilar, Did you copy/paste my code exactly? Works fine for me. Try restarting your session.

Comment: Hi, if the `n/a` is replaced with another value, say `33333`,  I will just have to remove `cond3` right?

Comment: @RickyAguilar, Yep, I mean that condition is irrelevant if there are no `n/a` values.

Comment: Thanks! Got it. Anyway, can you look at this too? If it's possible to do, that's cool. If not, that's also fine.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51338830/python-pandas-checking-for-a-value-if-it-exists-from-one-dataframe-to-another-da

Comment: @RickyAguilar, I'll try and have a look a little later!

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell `duplicated` that you want to mark all duplicates - by default it only marks everything but the first occurrence of a value:

`df['svc_no'].duplicated(keep=False)`

[see also the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html)